# printer settings import not working as system account

Tags: windows, printing

I'm trying to import the settings for printers via SCCM that runs installations in the system account.
Manually as User with Administrator rights, it's working as expected.
Manually as system account or over SCCM, it's not working.

Command I use:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "Zebra" /a "C:\Temp\Zebra.dat"
```

The file is where it's expected, the printer has the correct name, and it works as admin but not as system account.
Importing with the powershell "get-printconfiguration" / "Set-PrintConfiguration" doesn't work since it doesn't save the settings I need to transfer.
I don't have the possibility to run the script as an administrator or change settings on sccm, so those aren't solutions for my case.
I would have the ability to run it in the current user context, if there might be a possible way here, but as far as I checked just importing it as user doesn't work because of rights.

Any ideas how this can work as system account?

Comment: Running manually as system, does it return to the command prompt and not provide an error or message?

Comment: I start it in the command prompt as system and it doesn't give an error message. I can force an popup error message by entering wrong data, for example with a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found an workaround that works for me:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "Zebra" /a "C:\Temp\Zebra.dat" u
```

if I import like this as user, the import works as user and the settings I need are there.
This makes me think that I need a parameter to import as system to apply it for all users, but I haven't found out if that exactly is the problem and what I would need to fix it with the system account.
But for what I need it's "Good enough" :)